# Minimal Polynomial of $\alpha^2$

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Having already proved that $p(x)=x^5 + x^2 + 1$ is primitive in $GF(2)$ and assuming that $\alpha$ is a primitive element representing a root of $p(x)$, I am trying to minimal polynomial of $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^3$. I do not want anyone to solve this for me. Can someone point me to an authoritative source where I can read about this and then solve the problem myself?

Comment: By "$\;p(x)\;$ is primitive...", did you mean it is *irreducible*?

Comment: To be a primitive polynomial it has to be irreducible plus it has to satisfy one more property <-- This has already been proved.

Comment: So apparently you're relying on a particular definition, which I think it is no very widespread: a primitive pol. (of some fields extension) is an irreduc. polynomial of some primitive element of the extension, which also pressumes one knows a priori the extension's simple...ok.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I disagree. In the context of finite-fields the definition: primitive polynomial is the minimal polynomial of a generator of the multiplicative group of an extension field **is** standard :-)

Comment: @user100503: Are you familiar with the Frobenius automorphism? In characteristic two it takes the form $F(x)=x^2$. A basic property of the Frobenius automorphism is that if $\beta$ is a zero of a polynomial $p(x)\in GF(2)[x]$, then $F(\beta)$ is also a zero of $p(x)$. This will immediately settle the question of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^2$.

Comment: I am not familiar with Frobenius automorphism. I have found out that finding all conjugates _might_ help in determining the minimal polynomial but I am not too sure of that.

Comment: The conjugates of any element of $\beta\in GF(32)$, $\beta\notin GF(2)$ are $\beta$, $\beta^2$, $\beta^4$, $\beta^8$ and $\beta^{16}$. No point in going further, because $\beta^{32}=\beta$.

Comment: The following books in Galois Theory doesn't even mention it, @Jyrki: Milne's , Lorenz's (he just define *primitive polynomial* as I've always used it: one where the g.c.d of its coefficients is one), Morandi's (just as above), Howie's, Stewart's, Weintraub's (just as Lorenz's), Edwards's, Reid's, Jacobson's (Vol. III), Rotman's "Advanced Modern Algebra" (as Lorenz's), etc. Perhaps some more modern books use that notion more (though there are several modern books above), but I don't think it is a *standard* notion in the sense the OP used it...at least not for all.

Comment: @Don: Those books, while great, are not targeting finite fields specifically. Mind you, this is not the first time I have had this discussion in Math.SE. You are correct in that outside the circle of $\Bbb{F}_q$-people *primitive* usually means something else. Well, the meaning of *normal* in math also depends on the context. I apologize for phrasing it too strongly initially. I like to think I **know** what I'm talking about here.

Comment: I think I can agree with that, Jyrki: when dealing with finite fields, or even with positive characteristic ones, one could agree on what is a prim. pol. And what I like to think is *I'd like to know* what I'm talking about here most of the time...and not sure about that.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In this case my beta = alpha^2. If I have to determine the minimal polynomial of alpha^3 then the conjugates are  alpha^6, alpha^12, alpha^24. Is this correct?

Comment: You are missing one of the conjugates of $\alpha^3$. Namely $\alpha^{48}=\alpha^{31+17}=\alpha^{17}$. The Frobenius on $GF(32)$ is of order five, so you get back to the element you started with after squaring five times. Here $\alpha^{2\cdot 17}=\alpha^{34}=\alpha^3$, and we got back to $\alpha^3$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

One way of finding the minimal polynomial is the following.
You can write all the elements of $GF(32)=GF(2)[\alpha]$ as (at most) quartic polynomials in $\alpha$, and try to use that. Let $\beta=\alpha^3$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\beta^2&=\alpha^6=\\
&=\alpha^3+\alpha,\\
\beta^3&=\alpha^3\beta^2=\alpha^6+\alpha^4=\\
&=\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha,\\
\beta^4&=\beta(\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha)=\alpha^7+\alpha^6+\alpha^4=\\
&=\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha,\\
\beta^5&=\beta(\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha)=\alpha^6+\alpha^5+\alpha^4=\\
&=\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now finding a polynomial $p(x)=x^5+b_4x^4+b_3x^3+b_2x^2+b_1x+b_0$ with
the property $p(\beta)=0$ is equivalent to solving the unknown coefficients
$b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\in GF(2)$ from the linear system of equations that you get by equating like power of $\alpha$ from the two sides of
$$
(\beta^5=)\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=b_4\beta^4+b_3\beta^3+b_2\beta^2+b_1\beta+b_0
$$
with the aid of the above table of power of $\beta$.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Oops. The powers on the r.h.s. of the last equation were supposed to be powers of $\beta$.